# How to write a TestNG listener that can list all groups of a Test Method?

Tags: java, testng, listener

My sample testNG method is as below:

```
@Test(groups = { "regression", "sanity", "TTD-001" })
public void createProject() {
   //Some execution happens
}
```

Can we write a listener class, which can give me a string array of { "regression", "sanity", "TTD-001" } of the individual tests that were executed. Here the unique value TTD-001 has been mapped with a bug tracking utility that should be updated based on the execution status of the test method.

Is this possible, or please suggest any other possible ways to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html).  Implement afterInvocation() in the interface.
`method.getTestMethod().getGroups()` would give you the string array of the groups list and the result object would give the result of the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without a listener directly in you class:

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestContext context)
{
    context.getAllTestMethods()[0].getGroups();
}
```

Or implement ITestListener e.g.

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
{        
    result.getMethod().getGroups();
}

@Override
...
```